# Removing a unique_ptr from a list, by its value's pointer

Tags: c++, list, pointers, unique-ptr

Given a pointer to an object, I am trying to remove the same object from a list of `unique_ptrs`. I do this by matching each element of a raw pointer `list` subset of a larger `unique_ptr` list which definitely contains all of the elements from the subset `list`. Code:

Edit: For clarity, rawListSubset is `std::list<MyObj>` 
and smartListSet is `std::list< unique_ptr<MyObj> >`.

```
for (auto& deleteThis : rawListSubset)
{
    // Find the matching unique_ptr
    for (auto& smartPtrElement : smartListSet)
    {
        if (deleteThis == smartPtrElement.get()) 
        { 
            unique_ptr<Entity> local = move(smartPtrElement); 
            // Hence deleting the object when out of scope of this conditional
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, this doesn't work, but it puts across the idea of what I'm trying to do.

```
for (auto& deleteThis : rawListSubset)
{
    // Find the matching unique_ptr
    for (auto& smartPtrElement : smartListSet)
    {
        if (deleteThis == smartPtrElement.get()) 
        {

            smartListSet.remove(smartPtrElement);
            // After this, the API tries to erroneously copy the unique_ptr

        }
    }
}
```

How can I both delete the object that the pointer is pointing to, as well as safely remove it from its list?

Comment: What is the type of `smartListSet`?

Comment: A list of unique_ptrs. Specifically they are unique_ptrs to a class called Entity, but this is more of a general question for unique_ptrs to any object.

Comment: BTW, you should iterate by value over `rawListSubset`. It's more efficient for scalar types like pointers.

Comment: That's something I've always wondered about - what's the reasoning behind that?

Comment: A reference is generally implemented as a pointer (except in simple cases where the compiler can elide it out). So there is an extra level of indirection associated with accessing the object referred to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To safely remove elements from a `std::list` in a loop, you have to use iterators.  `std::list::erase()` removes an element specified by an iterator, and returns an iterator to the next element in the list:

```
for (auto& deleteThis : rawListSubset)
{
    // Find the matching unique_ptr
    auto i = smartListSet.begin();
    auto e = smartListSet.end();
    while (i != e)
    {
        if (deleteThis == i->get()) 
            i = smartListSet.erase(i);
        else
            ++i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahhh, erase, gotcha. Thanks for the explicit iteration method.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete elements by iterating over list by using iterators, rather than for range loop:

```
for (auto& deleteThis : rawListSubset)
{
    // Find the matching unique_ptr
    for (auto smartPtrIter = smartListSet.begin(); smartPtrIter != smartListSet.end(); )
    {
        if (deleteThis == smartPtrIter->get()) 
        {

            smartListSet.erase(smartPtrIter++);
        } else
            ++smartPtrIter;
    }
}
```

Object pointed by smart pointer will be deleted when you remove that element from the list, that what smart pointers are used for.